# Is there a better solution thant dt.weekofyear?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

Is there a better solution than `df['weekofyear'] = df['date'].dt.weekofyear`?

The problem of this solution is that, sometimes, the days after the last week of the year n but before the first week of the year n+1 are counted as week 1 and and not as week 0.

I am working with pyspark and koalas (no pandas allowed).

Here is an example:

[image: Problematic df]

As you can see, the first column is Date, the second one is week, the third is month and last is year.

Comment: could you show examples of some dates that suffer from this problem?

Comment: Yes of course, I edited the post

Comment: Date - Weekofyear - Month - Year. But the problem is only on the second column.

Comment: why would you want them to be week 0...? they are technically on the same week, though separated across the year.

Comment: Because I want to goupby(weekofyear) my data. And the problem is that for example, Week 1 tooks the real first week of 2019, but add the to it the last day of 2019 wich are counted as week 1 as well. It makes no sense.

Comment: @Joe Not really, similar problem but no viable solution

Comment: I guess you want them to be week 53, not week 0, right?

Comment: ISO 'week number' is only useful when paired with the *year* of the ISO week number, which won't necessarily be the calendar year. e.g., `date -d '2019-12-31' +%G-W%V` gives `2020-W01`. If there's no way to get that year, `weekofyear` is difficult to use correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want...? I suppose you can use `case when` to replace the undesired values of week of year.

```
df['weekofyear'] = df['date'].dt.weekofyear

df2 = ks.sql("""
select
    date,
    case when weekofyear = 1 and month = 12 then 53 else weekofyear end as weekofyear,
    month,
    year
from {df}""")
```

Comment: @Ousen92i I've added another way, which is more pythonic and pandas-like - see if that works for you?

Comment: When I tried the 2nd way, I got an error : 'Series' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @Ousen92i  okay, I didn't expect it to work anyway, how about the first one?